# run gradle task from intellij plugin development

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-plugin

I want to develop an IntelliJ plugin in which when user click on menu option it will run gradle task. I am using jdk 1.8 and trying below code

```
GradleConnector connector = GradleConnector.newConnector();
connector.forProjectDirectory(new File(mProject.getBasePath()));
ProjectConnection connection = connector.connect();
BuildLauncher build = connection.newBuild();
build.forTasks("myTask");;
build.setStandardOutput(System.out);
build.run();
```

but getting error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/gradle/internal/jvm/UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue. I resolved it by adding gradle-base-services-2.1.jar in classpath/buildpath .

**Add below jars in your classpath** to be able to run this program successfully

1. gradle-base-services-2.1.jar
2. gradle-tooling-api-2.1.jar
3. guava-jdk5-17.0.jar
4. slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar